# Android Contact List

Tags: android

Is it possible to password protect contact list via programatically?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I mean it's possible... but, but there are many obstacles in this way:

1. Contact list is a special kind of content which handled by special `ContentProvider`, so if you will encrypt contact list which is in fact simple SQLite table(s) Android built-in ContentProvider for exposing contact list won't be able to work correctly.
2. So in order to encrypt contact list you have to 1st completely rewrite contact list ContentProvider

Comment: is there any need of encrypting the list? is it possible to password protect like in pdf,excel etc

Comment: @UNNI: I don't know - you asked about encrypting contact list... Never checked but I'm pretty sure, that contacts stored as simple unencrypted SQLite table. So if you're going to hide some data you'd definitely need to encrypt data or use special software. BTW I'm preparing this kind of app (encrypted storage of contacts, passwords in Android phone)